# vscode quickly select and comment code block without using mouse

Tags: visual-studio-code

Hi guys suppose i want to comment the below code in `vscode`

```
files_converted.forEach( ( item , idx ) => {
        zip_Directory( `${req.body.outputPath}/${item}` ,  `${req.body.outputPath}/${item}.zip` );
    })
    .then( () => {
        console.log('FILES CONVERTED AND ZIPPED !')
    }).catch( (err) => 
        { console.error(err) 
    });
```

Is there anyway of quickly selecting and commenting out the above code without using the mouse ? The comment style i prefer is ( `/* some comment here */` ).

Comment: Have you already tried selecting the lines and using Ctrl+/ (or Command+/  on Mac) ? If you also want a quick way to select you can google VS Code Smart Select

Comment: @ChatterOne ctrl + / will comment in this style  `//` , i preferably want it in `/* this style */`

Answer (score 3):

- To select something inside curly brackets, you can use smart select. The idea is that you can select the text inside curly brackets and "expand" the selection or "shrink" it. The default keyboard shortcut on Mac is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to grow and the left arrow to shrink.
- To use block comments instead of line comments you can use ... well, the "block comment" function :-P Which by default is <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

for bracket selection, use this...

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbankier.vscode-quick-select

for block comment, 
use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>